# Does it true that in moment of heavy load on cluster Elasticsearch can make inaccurate aggregations?

Tags: elasticsearch

Recently I spoke with a consultant of Elasticsearch about aggregating data in the database and got some confusing answer about Elasticsearch. Does it true that in moment of heavy load on cluster Elasticsearch can make inaccurate aggregations?

Answer (score 0):

OK, after some investigations found following discussions on elastic forums that answers my question

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/background-count-in-significant-terms-not-consistent/55824/7

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/poc-elastic-search-correctness-exactitude-of-stats/155881